# MongoDB lookup with object relation instead of array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `matches` like this. I'm using `players` object `{key: ObjectId, key: ObjectID}` instead of classic array `[ObjectId, ObjectID]` for reference `players` collection

```
{    
 "_id": ObjectId("5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d55"),
 "date": "01/01/2020",
 "players": {
   "home": ObjectId("5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d59"),
   "away": ObjectId("5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d60")
 }
},
{...}
```

And `players` collection:

```
{    
 "_id": ObjectId("5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d59"),
 "name": "Roger Federer"
 "country": "Suiza"
},
{    
 "_id": ObjectId("5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d60"),
 "name": "Rafa Nadal"
 "country": "España"
},
{...}
```

What's the better way to do mongoDB `lookup`? something like this is correct?

```
  const rows = await db.collection('matches').aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "players",
                    localField: "players.home",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "players.home"                
                }            
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "players",
                    localField: "players.away",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "players.away"                
                },
            { $unwind: "$players.home" },
            { $unwind: "$players.away" },         
            }]).toArray()
```

I want output like this:

```
{
 _id: 5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d55,
 date: "12/05/20",
 players: { 
   home: {
     _id: 5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d59,
     name: "Roger Federer",
     country: "Suiza"
   },
   away: {
     _id: 5eb93f8efd259cd7fbf49d60,
     name: "Rafa Nadal",
     country: "España"
   } 
 }
}
{...}
```

Comment: Could you give some examples of your expected output?

Comment: updated question

Comment: The query provided by you, is yielding the expected output. Are you getting any different error/issue?

Comment: I want to know if it is the most optimal way or is there a better way to do it

Comment: Yes, its correct, but if the collections are huge, then you can improve the performance by applying indexing.

Comment: @whoami's thought must be considered. Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.matches.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "players",
        localField: "players.home",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "home"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "players",
        localField: "players.away",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "away"
      }
    },
    /** Check output of lookup is not empty array `[]` & get first doc & write it to respective field, else write the same value as original */
    {
      $project: {
        date: 1,
        "players.home": { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$home", [] ] }, "$players.home", { $arrayElemAt: [ "$home", 0 ] } ] },
        "players.away": { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$away", [] ] }, "$players.away", { $arrayElemAt: [ "$away", 0 ] } ] }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ul1V-yHPiXp)

**Changes or Issues with current Query :**

1) As you're using two `$unwind` stages one after the other, If anyone of the field either `home` or `away` doesn't have a matching document in `players` collection then in the result you don't even get actual `match` document also, But why ? It's because if you do `$unwind` on `[]` (which is returned by lookup stage) then unwind will remove that parent document from result, To overcome this you need to use [preservenullandemptyarrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#preservenullandemptyarrays) option in `unwind` stage.

2) Ok, there is another way to do this without actually using `$unwind`. So do not use `as: "players.home"` or `as: "players.away"` cause you're actually writing back to original field, Just in case if you don't find a matching document an empty array `[]` will be written to actual fields either to `"home"` or `"away"` wherever there is not match (In this case you would loose actual `ObjectId()` value existing in that particular field in matches doc). So write output of lookup to a new field.

Or **even more efficient way**, instead of two `$lookup` stages (Cause each `lookup` has to go through docs of `players` collection again & again), you can try one lookup with [multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) :

```
db.matches.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "players",
        let: { home: "$players.home", away: "$players.away" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: { $expr: { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$home" ] }, { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$away" ] } ] } }
          }
        ],
        as: "data"
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yq7pYeCnfIX)

**Note :** Here all the matching docs from `players` which match with irrespective of `away` or `home` field will be pushed to `data` array. So to keep DB operation simple you can get that array from DB along with actual matches document & Offload some work to code which is to map respective objects from `data` array to `players.home` & `players.away` fields.